# Java Memory Allocation upper limit Sci2 in Mac

Tags: java, macos, networking, memory, social-networking

Hardware: 64bit Mac with two 4Gb cores
Program: Sci2
Language: Java
Issue: memory allocation upper limit.

I have increased Xmx from 256m to 2100m, and Sci2 is able to use up to 1.92Gb (according to activity monitor). This is still not enough to compute a network with 300k nodes and about 2 million edges. Below is the program

-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
-vmargs
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/scisip128.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Xms40m
-Xmx2100m
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts

Need more memory, any suggestions?

Comment: Your description of "two 4GB cores" doesn't make sense to me.  Do you mean 2 cores and 4Gb of memory?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a 32bit JVM, you are limited to somewhere between 2 and 3Gb by the operating system and the 32bit instruction set.  (It depends on the operating system ... but you lose up to 1/4 of the 32bit virtual address space to the OS, and up to 1/4 to the "stack" space.

So you are most likely going to need to install a 64bit JVM.  You can get 64bit Java for Mac OS X from the Oracle Java downloads.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I have tried this and I am unable to increase beyond 2100m. However I can now use 2.2GB of real memory. Will try a few other things and see how it goes...

Comment: A 64bit JVM can go *way* bigger than 2Gb.  Are you sure you installed it properly?  Are you sure you have configured the Eclipse application launcher to use it?

Comment: thanks Stephen. i have created a virtual box from oracle and downloaded ubuntu 64 bit linux as the OS. linux is the only platform where Sci2 can run as 64 bit (i missed this which is allot dumb!). problem partly solved as the upper limit of memory to the Sci2 JVM is now at least 6000M, however i'm not sure about how the memory is being shared amongst virtual box/ubuntu/sci2. going through some trial and error to see what the best configuration is. I hope to have sci2 on after burner soon so as to produce larger network maps ...